# error to read serial ports using R serial-package

Tags: r, serial-port

I am trying to read the COM ports using the library serial, but the command listPorts() is not working:

Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") :
[tcl] unable to open key: The system cannot find the file specified..

I also noticed a conflict, but I am not sure if this is related to the previous problem:

"Attaching package: ‘serial’
The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:
isOpen"

I installed different package versions, but it is still not working.
Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. The registry keys are located in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` but this folder is only created if devices are connected via COM ports. So, the `listports()` will only work when a device is connected.